# libv41-dev package can't be located for installation

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, mjpeg

I am trying to stream jpgs using Motion JPEG streamer. I need to install package libv41-dev as a required library and when I install `sudo apt-get install libv41-dev`, I get `Unable to locate package libv41-dev` error. Why can't locate that package? I searched in google for that `libv41-dev`, not much information has come out. That library is required for `linux/videodev.h` file. Thanks

Comment: I changed to libv4l-dev. It is 4l(four and alphabet l) not 41 (fourty one).

Answer (score 8):

The library is `libv4l-dev`. You can install using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
```

Comment: I'm going to pretend that this didn't just help me and that I can in fact see properly

Answer (score 6):

Make sure it’s not libv41 it’s libv4l ( letter l )